# Rollback required to catch all exceptions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions

I am working on a MySQL database and my question is two fold related to each other,

1. Do we require a rollback if an error were to occur during a transaction, as it would only commit changes if it reached the last line of execution (which would be the commit statment), if not dosent it automatically rollback
2. If there needs to be required a rollback then I was wondering if there was any new way introduced or any workaround for catching **'ALL'** exceptions, similar to SQL server where you try and catch error and if any error occurs you rollback

My main Concerns are power outage, as it is common where I live and if the electricity is cut to the server (which would be nothing but a database installed on a PC shared through adhoc / wifi connection, not a dedicated server) in between a transaction, then useful statements might not execute like logging in transaction

Comment: So your scenario is: A transaction is ongoing, some INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE operations have been executed in it, and then a power outage happens before any commit is executed. Then the data won't be changed at all; it's as if the all operations in the transaction never happened. When the power comes back up you won't see those INSERTs, UPDATEs, or DELETEs (they were never committed).

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes but what if an insert error where to occur, wouldn't the same logic apply, as again the commit statement is at the last and wouldn't execute, if an error was thrown in between

Comment: If an error occurs in an INSERT the database engine will throw an error or exception. Now, your application should have code to catch it and deal with it (ignore it, roll back to a save point if available, take a compensating action, roll back the whole transaction, etc.). In short, it's up to your app to decide if the transaction should continue or not: the database engine will obey the app. If the app commits the transaction in the end, all successful operations will be committed, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If a transaction is not committed, and any of the following happen, it will be rolled back:

- Power loss on your PC
- Reboot on your PC
- MySQL Server process crashes or is killed
- Client application exits without committing transaction. The MySQL Server will detect the client is gone, and abort that client's session. This rolls back a transaction if one was open. This also happens if the network connection between client and server is dropped.

Comment: Thank you for replying ,but what if an insert error where to occur, wouldn't the same logic apply, as again the commit statement is at the last and wouldn't execute, if an error was thrown in between transaction, and if that happened is there a way to catch all errors that might occur rather than declaring every error type like in a try catch from sql server